# How do you rotate an image along the Y-axis with Flash Builder 4.6?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

Good afternoon,
I am trying to rotate a image using rotationY but it always rotates based off of the left side of the image is there a way to change the rotation point to be the center of the image? Is seems like you should be able to use the transformAround() method but I am having problems finding a example of the transformAround that has to do with images. Does anyone have any examples of how do this or am a going about this the wrong way? What i am trying to do is build a slide show that rotates around and you tap on the images to enlarge.
Thank for your help sorry for the long winded question.

Comment: are you using the Flex framework or just vanilla AS3?

Comment: The flex frame work. I am building it all into a android air application. The slide show will be on a tablet. I also wouldn't mind knowing if there are any books if the answer is just to broad. I could be thinking that its simpler then it is. Thanks for your replay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the Flex framework, you can use the Spark 3D effects to rotate images, rather than fuss with transforms.  See the example below (you can easily replace the `Rect` with your Image). The `autoCenterTransform` attribute of Rotate3D does all the work of moving the x,y,z rotation point to the center of the object.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:Rotate3D 
            id="rotateEffect"
            target="{myImage}"
            angleYFrom="0"
            angleYTo="360"
            duration="1000" 
            autoCenterTransform="true"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Button label="Rotate" 
              x="10" y="10"
              click="rotateEffect.play()"/>

    <s:Rect id="myImage" 
             x="20" y="40"
             height="100" width="100">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0xABABAB"/>
        </s:fill>   
    </s:Rect>

</s:Application>
```

Alternatively, if you do not want to completely center the transform point, but only shift the transform point to allow for the Y rotation, you can adjust the `transformX` property of your image, as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:Rotate3D 
            id="rotateEffect"
            target="{myImage}"
            angleYFrom="0"
            angleYTo="360"
            duration="1000" 
            />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Button label="Rotate" 
              x="10" y="10"
              click="rotateEffect.play()"/>

    <s:Rect id="myImage" 
             x="20" y="40"
             height="100" width="100" 
             transformX="{myImage.width/2}">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0xABABAB"/>
        </s:fill>   
    </s:Rect>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: That is exactly the answer to the question I was looking for! I just was wandering do you know of any more information that I could read to learn more about this? Books or articles if not its cool you did more then answer my question so thank you very much!

Comment: I got all this info from the [Adobe docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/effects/Rotate3D.html).  There is also a nice example [here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/10/13/3d-rotating-objects-in-flex-using-the-fxrotate3d-effect-and-flash-player-10/).